# Delete rows from list

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a macro to delete all records from my Excel table, except for the first row (as that's where several formulas as stored. The number of records in my table is changing, so it needs to be flexible. I am currently using the following code:

```
Sheets("5. Informatieproducten Index").Select
Range("A6").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Delete
```

Please help!.

Tnx

Answer (score 2):

By detecting the last row and last column of your data :

```
LastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
LastCol =  Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(LastRow,LastCol)).Clear
```

Comment: Many thanks for your support on this! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
Sheets("5. Informatieproducten Index").Range("A2:XFD1048576").Delete
```

This deletes the information of all cells, from A2 (just under the first row) to XFD1048576 (which is the most right-bottom cell possible).

Comment: Be aware: you mentioned only the first row in your explanation, so I built this command on the second row. However your code starts, not at A2, but at A6. I don't know why, but you might be careful about this (not deleting too much).

Answer (score 0):

There are so many diferent ways to do that. Before all you need to declare a variable to always look for the last row of you table. Then the next step is to look all the lines below the first row of your table and the last row that you previously declared. Note that you can clean or delete the rows. Obs: clean is the method that you keeps the format of your cell and table. Delete is the method that you remove all the formats.

```
Sub deleteRows()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim firstRow As Integer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("5. Informatieproducten Index")

'first Row of your table - you can do diferents things to take always the first row of your table
firstRow = ws.Range("A5").Row

'you need to take care if there is any blank cell in the interval
lastRow = ws.Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row

ws.Range("A" & firstRow & ":A9" & lastRow).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for your support on this! Much appreciated.